# Install multiple versions apk from a same project

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, version

I have developed an Android project with Android Studio and I want to install it on a device. The problem is that I want to install 2 versions of it. The only difference between them will only be the name.

I hope that you could help me.

Answer (score 0):

As well as the name you will also have to change the applicationId.
The applicationId is what Android uses to detect if an app is unique.

If you are using gradle it will be within your modules build.gradle file like this

```
...
android {
...
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mycompany.appname"
...
    }
```

You may also have to change `provider` authorities in your `AndroidManifest.xml` if you use them.